# How to view node.js console.log from live azure site

Tags: node.js, azure, console.log

I'm trying to view my node.js console logs from a live azure site. The middle tier is a combination of .Net and node.

What I've tried so far that has not worked:

1. `az webapp log tail --name <name of webapp> --resource-group <name of resource group>`    (functioned but didn't show me the console.log messages)
2. I tried enabling application logging and web server logging in the web app's "app service logging". I saw some error information in /LogFiles/DetailedErrors. However I did not see any console.log messages.
3. I tried going to this url: https://{{ name of webapp }}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream but it never reached an endpoint.

4. I checked my  iisnode.yml had a key named logDirectory with a value set to iisnode.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the logs via the kudu console for web apps? https://www.gslab.com/blogs/kudu-azure-web-app

Comment: Hey, @Jonny Mac, can you see the console.log now? Please post a comment to let me know, or just accept the answer.

Comment: @DorisLv this is great, thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear you solve your problem, would you mind accept my answer for others to refer? @Jonny Mac

Comment: Hi, if any others' answer helps you solve the problem, please [mark the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2eE3.jpg) to end the question. This is very important.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I test the nodejs project with this code:(modify from git: [nodejs-docs-hello-world](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world))

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log('########my console log##########');
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World!");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

Then I deploy it from VS Code.

The next step is enable **Application Logging**.
On Linux it looks like this:
[image]

On windows it looks like this:
[image]

Finally, in **Kudu**(https://{{ name of webapp }}.scm.azurewebsites.net)->**log stream**, you can see these console logs:
[image]